# How to avoid making too many requests to download image from server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I am rendering a map with some background pattern so my map `render` function is like this:

```
let image = new Image();

render(position) {
    var drawBackground = function (callback) {      
      callback(this);
    }

    image.onload = drawBackground(() => {
      this.ctx.setTransform(this.scale, 0, 0, this.scale, -position.x, -position.y);
      var pattern = this.ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');
      this.ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
      this.ctx.fillRect(position.x, position.y, this.width, this.height);
    });

    image.src = require('background.jpg');
}
```

And this `render` function is called in my animate function in `main.js` so it is executed many times during `requestAnimationFrame`.

I use `require` in this line

```
image.src = require('background.jpg');
```

because I use webpack in Node.js server end. But this code will make a request to the server in every round of animation so it is consuming a lot of resources. How to avoid making too many request to the server? I guess the image is cached in the browser?  But when I profile the code I can see it is attempting to make many requests to the server. Will this code affect performance? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Move that code outside the `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: @Oriol I want to do so but how can I get the animation loop to render my map?

Comment: @Oriol I see!! I just need to move `image.src = require('background.jpg');` outside of `render` function. Thank you so much. But I don't see much performance improve so that is unexpected.

Comment: Are you certain it is making the request to the server every time, check your server logs. I would have thought that after the first request your browser will cache the result and subsequent requests will get the image out of browser cache rather than make the network call.

Comment: @bhspencer yes I can see it is making many requests in Chrome dev tool -> Network. Although I agree that the browser has cached the image the network section shows me it is continuously attempting to make requests from the server. If I move the line out of the `render` function it only makes one call to the server, which I think is just enough.